# Override a Widget on a Default Layer in Orchard

Tags: widget, orchardcms

I'm very new to Orchard so please bear with me if this is a simple fix. I have a standard header that is currently on all my pages so it is in the default layer. In one section of my site I would like to use a different header. When I add Header B to that section it shows up and the header from the default layer show up. Is there any way to have only Header B show up?

I'm thinking I need to override the header zone from the default layer but I have no idea how.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the default layer so that it has "not [whatever condition you have on the other layer]" as the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You must exclude the desired url from the default layer as Bertrand says.

I think that the default layer has the "true" rule so you should be able to use

true and not url("~/new-header-url")

then create a layer with the new header and the rule

url("~/new-header-url")

Regards.